# HP G70 laptop's screen often has striation lines on it, why?

Tags: display, laptop-repair

My daughter's HP G70 laptop often will have striation lines on it, making it unusable.  We've noticed that sometimes if you press down hard on the main unit, near the hinge where the screen is, that sometimes that clears up the striated lines and you can use it again, but this doesn't always fix it.  What could be causing the striated lines and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often caused by either broken parts or a loose connector.

Given that pressing down near the hinge (where a flat cable is usually connects the laptop's main board to the LCD) it is likely the latter.

HP's [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01573159.pdf) shows that part of your laptop as follows (see page 3-2).
[image: Part of a HP manual. Showing the display and connector]

This is usually easy to fix yourself (I have done it half a dozen times), but that will void your warranty. If it still under some warranty: Let the manufacturer fix it.

If you feel comfortable doing so yourself:

- Download the maintenance manual and read it.
- Get tape and a (digital) camera. A phone with a build in camera will do.
- Carefully disassemble only the needed parts. Take pictures. Tape down screws.
- Disconnect the flat cable to the screen, then reconnect it.

Test if possible; reassemble if it works.

If it does not work then you can either disassemble the screen and check that for faults, but that is usually a lot harder to do. If you go that way check the manual, page 3-9/

Comment: Thank you very much, Hennes, I'll find the manual online and do as you suggested.  I doubt my daughter still has the manual anyway.

Comment: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01573159.pdf

Comment: I don't know if my daughter's PC was a Compaq Presario.  Now that I have access to her laptop it's model number is G70-467CL, which doesn't look like it's a Presario.  HP's website ( http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/manualCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=3979161& ) doesn't help much, as far as the right kind of manual.